# Stopping redis is causing the /redis/ folder under /var/run/ to be deleted

Tags: redis

I have a setup where I am running redis on a socket. In the config I have the path for the socket to /var/run/redis/redis.sock. Everytime redis is stopped, the folder /redis/ is removed from /var/run/ together with the .sock file. So when trying to start redis again, it will not start since the folder is missing. I have to manually create the folder before starting.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue wit 3.2, 4.0 and 5.0 versions, the dirrerence is that i'm using multi instances of redis, each restart completely removes everything what is inside /var/run/redis and the dir itself

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little bit too late to the party, but I saw this very same behavior because I had installed `redis` both using `snap` and `apt` on my Debian 12 VM.

Removing the snap installation using `snap remove redis` and then starting the service using `service redis start` even recreated the folder at `/var/run/redis` and the sock file inside it.

Bear in mind that `/var/run/redis` created by starting the redis service will have `redis:redis` as the owner and if by chance your `www-data` user or group wants to access this folder, it won't be able to. Use `sudo chown -R redis:www-data /var/run/redis` to grant `www-data` access to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

temp solution would be to point your sockets to /var/lib/redis-sockets/
meanwhile "/var/lib/redis/" will be protected from outside use

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/redis-sockets/
chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis-sockets/
```

another solution would be to let users to read "/var/lib/redis" and point redis sockets there

edit: additionally you can use /var/run/redis-sockets as directory - so you can gain max performance (in-memory) but you have to override systemd little bit by adding few lines to your service config (override.conf):

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=redis-sockets
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```